# Automation test of AngularJS app hosted under CefSharp browser in WPF by using Protractor

Tags: wpf, protractor, ui-automation, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

we have a wpf application that uses cefsharp browser to host web site (AngularJS) - in other words - hybrid application.

We're interested to run an automation test (especially on the angular part). 
From a small research we saw that TestComplete supports cef browser hooking in native code, but we want to see all the possibilities.

Also as we saw that there is "Protractor" framework that is very suitable to test Angular based applications. 
The problems, for us, are that it can test only the web-part and it tests it by opening a web-browser. Anyway, we would like to run a protractor tests on the browser instance that is running inside the native code(wpf). Is it possible? Do you have another alternatives/ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Should be possible, quick check and it looks like it's based on `Chrome Driver`, so check out the `CEF` guide. See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to **amaitland**

I took his suggestion and succeeded to run a protractor tests on CefSharp hosted web browser.

In order to do this  you have to do 2 things:

1. Define debugging port in .net application (on start up) that hosts embedded cef web browser:

   ```
           var settings = new CefSettings { RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088 };
           Cef.Initialize(settings);
   ```
2. In protractor configuration file this full debugging address "ip:port" should be defined under capabilities:

   ```
        seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        specs: ['./tests.spec.js'],
        capabilities: {

              'browserName': 'chrome',

              'chromeOptions': {'debuggerAddress': "127.0.0.1:8088" }
        }
   ```
3. Run .net application and enter the screen with the hosted web browser
4. Run protractor configuration.js

Comment: Can you ellaborate on the meaning of "Run protractor configuration.js". I added an item in the menu to the CefSharp wrapper to run open up a command line window and run protractor. When the tests run, they open up a new chromium browser instead of running the tests within the CefSharp application. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using Cypress?
please help.

Comment: can we achieve this without using debuggeraddress <hostname/ip:port>, In my case the address to our application <hostname/ip:port> has been blocked/Access Removed. Unable to use this method due to access restriction with our app, is there any other way to connect to CEF browser?